# How to dynamically load script file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using getScript to load a script file from another  domain :

```
 $.getScript("URL to other domain", function(script, textStatus, jqXHR)
 {
    alert(script)          // =======> undefined
    alert(textStatus)      // =======> success
    alert(jqXHR)           // =======> Object
 });
```

The script file is loaded successfully in the browser but i want to access the text from the script file. How can i do this and why script is undefined ?

Comment: The script might be getting cached. Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: yes i tried but still script is undefined in the callback

Comment: I'm betting that you can't access the text content of the script across domains (for the usual same origin policy reasons) and that this is just jQuery silently dropping it without warning (or even documentation in the API docs). (jQuery really is shonky, its shockingly like PHP in its ubiquity, low barriers to entry, and assorted insanities and holes)

Comment: The same origin policy is a firewall between "Content loaded into browser memory from other websites" and "JavaScript written by the author of the current website". `getScript`'s ability to load the file into browser memory is meaningless in the face of the same origin policy.

Comment: It's not possible. The content is not loaded by jQuery, but the url is add to a <script> tag and loaded by the browser.

Comment: Is the functionality loaded? For example, after `getScript` has finished, are functions defined in the script file available?